# Using P-Channel Mosfet as reverse polarity protection and load switch

Tags: mosfet, switches, protection

I was wondering if a reverse polarity protection P-channel Mosfet could be used in addition with a small switch on the same circuit.

As an example, the image has the original circuit (A) and the other with the addition of a switch (B), that would pull the gate to VCC (turning the mosfet off) or GND (turning the mosfet on).

[image]

The benefit I see is that a small switch could turn a high current circuit on and off while still using the same component for reverse polarity protection.

The thing that worries me is the Mosfet's body diode. Will it conduct even when the switch is turning the mosfet off? And is there any other better way to so this?

Comment: *"the Mosfet's body diode. Will it conduct even when the switch is turning the mosfet off?"* Yes. Have you searched for "back-to-back" mosfets? There are many posts here about this configuration.

Comment: Flip the FET, swapping pin 2 & 3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in 'B', even if the MOSFET is off, the body diode will are forward biased (with a normal polarity input V); therefore the circuit won't be 'off'.

Best to put the switch in series with the PMOS device.